# Is it possible to create a dynamic period based on a date?

Tags: date, dynamic, google-bigquery, period

I am doing an analysis of ex-clients using key data points such as website conversion rate.
For each data point I want to see the value of the data point (e.g. conversion rate) for the 6 month period prior to their cancellation date.

Using the cancellation date (which varies per client) I want to be able to produce the data for a bulk group of clients.

Is this possible or does anyone have any ideas for a workaround in BigQuery?

Comment: Hi there - are you using the BigQuery UI for this? Do you have the option to use the API via a language like Python? This would give you a more flexibility. Are you able to share any code examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks Ben - I actually worked it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to query data based on a date, you can take a look at **Datetime functions**. You can get the day difference as an int64 (DATETIME_DIFF) and treat that to get your statistics. You will find more information in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions)